# Adding root named DNS zone in AD environment

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, internal-dns, dns-zone

We have a test environment with root AD domain named corp.testdomain.net with AD integrated DNS. For Exchange tests, messaging team has asked if we can create testdomain.net zone on DNS server. Surely it would help to have a testdomain.net as a root AD domain from the beginning but this is what we have inherited.
  What could be possible implications of adding additional AD integrated testdomain.net zone on DNS? My gut feeling says that while this is not going to break anything, it may introducte some headaches in the future...

Comment: You can Define records in your internal DNS. And as long as those required before external DNS source they will bee active however if you make a change it could take some time for the change to be reflected based on DNS caching.

Comment: `Surely it would help to have a testdomain.net as a root AD domain from the beginning` - No. You shouldn't use the "root" domain internally. You should use an unused subdomain of the root domain, just as you already have. `What could be possible implications of adding additional AD integrated testdomain.net zone on DNS?` - That depends. What operating system are your internal DNS servers running?

Comment: windows 2012 R2